# Select rows where column name not equals multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating friend system,where users able to add as friend,accept friend request etc....

Table Structure

```
userfr_id(AUTO_INCREMENT)
user_id
friend_id
accepted(int 1)
```

Working functions

```
Friend request
Accept friend request
Display all friends..
```

Not Working functions

- Delete friends
- Cancel Friend request
- check friend exits

Now i'm try to delete users as follow method

- check user id and friend_id available row
- get auto increment
- use auto increment to run delete query

But my problem is any method available to check user id and friend_id available row ??

sample date in table row

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xqZP9oF.png]

i couldn't use where in because filed name are different

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayby just try with:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE ( ( user_id = 4 AND friend_id = 5 ) OR
         ( user_id = 5 AND friend_id = 4 ) )              
   AND accepted = 1
```

If it returns one row, there is friendship, otherwise, they are not friends.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE !(ISNULL([columnname]));

TRy this place your query and additional condition